# Can't send wake on lan with .NET Core, when on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, udpclient

I'm trying to send a wake on lan packet from a .NET Core MVC application.

It works flawlessly if the application is hosted on a Windows host, but when it's running on my Raspberry Pi 3 (with Ubuntu Mate), I get the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
An unhandled exception has occurred: Permission denied 255.255.255.255:40000
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (0x80004005): Permission denied 255.255.255.255:40000
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
```

I'm using this to send the WOL packet:

```
public static bool WakeUp(string macAddress)
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        try
        {
            byte[] mac = null;

            // Parse string to byte array
            string[] macDigits = null;
            if (macAddress.Contains("-"))
            {
                macDigits = macAddress.Split('-');
            }
            else
            {
                macDigits = macAddress.Split(':');
            }

            if (macDigits.Length != 6)
            {
                //incorrect MAC address
            }
            else
            {
                mac = macDigits.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
            }

            if (mac != null)
            {

                // WOL packet is sent over UDP 255.255.255.0:40000.
                UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
                client.Client.Connect(IPAddress.Broadcast, 40000);

                // WOL packet contains a 6-bytes trailer and 16 times a 6-bytes sequence containing the MAC address.
                byte[] packet = new byte[17 * 6];

                // Trailer of 6 times 0xFF.
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    packet[i] = 0xFF;
                // Body of magic packet contains 16 times the MAC address.
                for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                        packet[i * 6 + j] = mac[j];

                // Submit
                int result = client.Client.Send(packet);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    retVal = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

I changed the port to 2050 for testing purposes -> same error.

Just in case it's important, here's the content of Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://*:80")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .Build();
    }
```

Any idea what's the cause of this? The rest of the application works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me after enabling broadcast:

```
// UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
client.EnableBroadcast = true;
```